# having trouble while using token::generate function for CSRF protection

Tags: php, session-cookies, csrf, session-variables, csrf-token

this is my token class.

```
class Token  {
    public static function generate(){
        return session::put(config::get('session/token_name'),md5(uniqid()));
    }}
```

and following code where i use it for generating the token

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
```

in the same file i use the php for validating it:

```
if (Token::check(input::get('token'))) {
///all the code
```

but it didn't work out

```
<?php
require_once('core\init.php');

if (input::exists()) {
   if (Token::check(input::get('token'))) {
 
   }

}

?>
```

when i comment this line of code my website works fine.. But without security

Comment: Are you using some kind of PHP framework? If so, which one? Just wondering where all your PHP classes and methods are coming from....

Comment: I'm not using any framework. I am a beginner and learning php oops so i've created all that by myself in separate classes.

Comment: Well, I cannot help you because all the relevant code is hidden away in those classes. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).